# What are the possible Argument Namespaces for Logos

Tags: magento2, image, xml

I am tweaking my theme using the xml approach.

I have this xml code:

```
<referenceBlock name="logo">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/my-override-logo.png</argument>
        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">160</argument>
        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">240</argument>
        <argument name="logo_img_alt" xsi:type="string">Alt string for SEO and Accessibility purposes</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

My alt string is not correctly coded because I can't get the alt attribute string to render to the page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure about this, but it looks like they changed the key to logo_alt and did not update it in the themes: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Theme/Block/Html/Header/Logo.php#L78

So it will take the value from the backend configuration if nothing else is defined for logo_alt

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative option to do it via admin:

Navigate in admin `Stores->Design->Header->Logo Image Alt = 'Put your desired title'`

save the config and refresh the cache it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and did not find any documentation about this online.

To solve it using the XML approach you can use "logo_alt" like this :

```
<argument name="logo_alt" xsi:type="string">Alt string for SEO and Accessibility purposes</argument>
```

This is working for sure with Magento 2.2.5.